# How can I get the total number of milliseconds from a TIME value

Tags: sql-server, time

Essentially, I want to the equivalent of .NET's `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`, but for the TIME datatype in SQLServer. The best I've been able to come up with is:

```
DATEDIFF(ms, CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(DATETIME2, value)), CONVERT(DATETIME2, value))
```

However, this is super verbose and pretty non-obvious. Is there a more concise/built-in way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server's `time` data type is designed to hold a *time of day*, not a *time span*. If you try to use it to hold a time span, you'll usually encounter awkward edge cases that lead to issues (no support for negatives, values greater than 24 hours nor for e.g. addition). I'd usually recommend *storing* timespan data in SQL Server as an `int` with a solid indication of which units are being used in the column name (e.g. `elapsedTimeMs`), rather than trying to place it in a `time` column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something in your question, you don't even need to do a `CONVERT` at all.  The `DATEDIFF()` function supports the `TIME` datatype:

```
Declare @T1 Time = '01:00:00',
        @T2 Time = '01:00:01'

Select  DateDiff(Millisecond, @T1, @T2)
```

> 1000

```
Declare @T1 Time = '01:00:00.000',
        @T2 Time = '01:00:00.123'

Select  DateDiff(Millisecond, @T1, @T2)
```

> 123

Comment: @ChaseMedallion what's that all about?  Is it even valid SQL?  It has 5 brackets in total

Comment: @ChaseMedallion DateAdd takes 3 arguments, not 2. And DateAdd was never in the original question.

Comment: For those who run across this answer in the future, the expression that matches my question using this is `DATEDIFF(ms, CONVERT(TIME, '00:00:00'), value)`